# XML Null Element Visual Basic

Tags: xml, vb.net, treeview

I made a program to edit xml files, and it works great until an element like `<Element />` appears.  When it happens, all Elements after it don't show up on the treeview.

Here's my code for populating the array:

```
Public Function ReadXML() As String
    Try
        Dim iLevel As Integer = 0
        Dim iIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim oReader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(sFilePath)

        Do While (oReader.Read())
            Select Case oReader.NodeType
                Case XmlNodeType.Element 'Display beginning of element.

                    If iIndex = 0 Then
                        ReDim aXML(0)
                    Else
                        ReDim Preserve aXML(iIndex)
                    End If

                    aXML(iIndex).Element = oReader.Name
                    aXML(iIndex).Layer = iLevel
                    iLevel += 1
                    iIndex += 1

                Case XmlNodeType.Text 'Display the text in each element.
                    aXML(iIndex - 1).Text = oReader.Value

                Case XmlNodeType.EndElement 'Display end of element.
                    iLevel -= 1
            End Select
        Loop
        oReader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Ocorreu um erro" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        cLog.WriteToErrorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, "Error")
    End Try
    Return ""
End Function
```

And here's the code for populating the treeview with the array.

```
Case ".xml"
                Dim oRootNode() As TreeNode
                Dim i As Integer
                Dim iParent As Integer
                Dim aParent() As String
                ReDim aParent(0)
                aParent(0) = i
                tvw.Nodes.Add(aParent(0), cXML.ReturnElement(0))
                oRootNode = tvw.Nodes.Find(aParent(0), True)

                For i = 1 To cXML.ReturnLength - 1
                    If Not i = cXML.ReturnLength - 1 Then

                        Select Case cXML.ReturnLayer(i + 1)
                            Case Is > cXML.ReturnLayer(i)
                                iParent += 1
                                ReDim Preserve aParent(iParent)
                                aParent(iParent) = i
                                oRootNode = tvw.Nodes.Find(aParent(iParent - 1), True)
                                oRootNode(0).Nodes.Add(i, cXML.ReturnElement(i))
                                oRootNode = tvw.Nodes.Find(aParent(iParent), True)
                            Case Is = cXML.ReturnLayer(i)
                                oRootNode(0).Nodes.Add(i, cXML.ReturnElement(i))

                            Case Is < cXML.ReturnLayer(i)
                                oRootNode = tvw.Nodes.Find(aParent(iParent), True)
                                oRootNode(0).Nodes.Add(i, cXML.ReturnElement(i))
                                iParent -= 1
                                oRootNode = tvw.Nodes.Find(aParent(iParent), True)
                        End Select
                    Else
                        oRootNode(0).Nodes.Add(i, cXML.ReturnElement(i))
                    End If

                Next
```

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Why do i find the answers 10 minutes after i post the questions.... i've been all morning trying to do this, and when i decide to ask for help, incomes the answer. and it's a simple one too.. just need to add 1 if.

Comment: Maybe explaining the question on SO triggered something ...

Comment: You can answer your own question--or you can delete it if you're not going to answer it.